# Fluent configuration for a collection and single property of same type

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have 2 classes, Type A has a single instance of Type B as well as a collection of Type B. I have tried various configurations but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly. If you could explain to me what I am doing wrong or give me a resource that would be helpful. I am getting better with these mappings but now and then they reach beyond my understanding apparently. I have narrowed down my classes to just the important properties.

**Clarification**

There will only ever be one sweepstakes related to an applicant, the applicant though will be located in the collection of applicants, and the winning entry will have the ID populated in the WinnerId field which I was hoping EF would map to the correct applicant.

**Error**

The navigation property 'Sweepstakes' declared on type 'NPlay.Common.Models.SweepstakesApplicant' has been configured with conflicting mapping information.

**Classes**

```
public SweepstakesConfiguration()
{
    Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("SweepstakesId");

    HasMany(c => c.Applicants)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Sweepstakes)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.SweepstakesId);

    HasOptional(c => c.WinningApplicant)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Sweepstakes)
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("WinnerId"));
}

public class SweepstakesApplicant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }        
    public int SweepstakesId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sweepstakes Sweepstakes { get; set; }
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings

```
public SweepstakesConfiguration()
{
    Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("SweepstakesId");

    HasOptional(c => c.WinningApplicant)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Sweepstakes)
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("WinnerId"));
}

public SweepstakesApplicantConfiguration()
{
    Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("SweepstakesApplicantId");

    HasRequired(a => a.Sweepstakes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Applicants)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.SweepstakesId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    HasRequired(c => c.Sweepstakes)
        .WithOptional(c => c.WinningApplicant)
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("SweepstakesId"));

    HasRequired(a => a.Buyer)
        .WithMany(b => b.SweepstakesApplications)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.BuyerId);

    HasRequired(a => a.Agent)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.AgentId);
}
```

Edit:  Updated mappings config and error.
Edit:  Fixed title further, amazing how many edits I have received, I wonder if this site would be better if people spent more time answering questions then just going around editing :D, hmm this will probably be edited as well.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think there is a circular dependency there, this could be the problem.

Comment: By first looks it seems so, but that's how you setup the navigation properties. The models themselves are solid i'm pretty sure, it is just the mapping. I think the problem lies where I have a single applicant as well as a collection of them. I probably need some other mapping setup that I am missing or misconfigured.

Comment: OK, sorry, in this case, I cannot help you further, I have not too much experience with code first :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the configuration I ended up with.

```
    public SweepstakesConfiguration()
    {
        Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("SweepstakesId");

        HasOptional(c => c.WinningApplicant)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.WinnerId);
    }

    public SweepstakesApplicantConfiguration()
    {
        Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("SweepstakesApplicantId");

        HasRequired(a => a.Sweepstakes)
            .WithMany(s => s.Applicants)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.SweepstakesId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        HasRequired(a => a.Buyer)
            .WithMany(b => b.SweepstakesApplications)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.BuyerId);

        HasRequired(a => a.Agent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.AgentId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same foreign key (`SweepstakesId`) in both the `one to zero-or-one` and `one-to-many` relation ships.

Either create a collection on the `SweepstakesApplicant` called `WinnerOfSweepstakes` or similar and say hasMany, or remove the navigation property from the mapping.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not following you. I have a collection of applicants. But I need to also reference just a single applicant that has won. It is the same model so it will use the same key, my Sweepstakes model has a WinnerId which is the FK to relate it back while the collection is a navigation property for the applicants who have entered.

Comment: I will add, on the SweepstakesConfig, I added the HasMany(c=>c.Applicants) extra trying to get this working but it could be completely wrong by being there. Regardless it wont work with or without and gives same error.